# Want to use Scrapy to scrape a website but not sure if there is a way around javascript

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, scrapy, http-headers

I have a list of schools IDs for schools in NYC. I want to collect publicly available budget data for each of those schools. The budget data is available from this website:

https://www.nycenet.edu/offices/d_chanc_oper/budget/dbor/galaxy/galaxybudgetsummaryto/default.aspx

I am using Python for this task and for browser automation I know scrapy is much faster than selenium. The issue is, though, I need to interact with the page. Namely, I have to enter the school ID as well as the year of interest (eventually I want to collect the budget data for each year). This interaction (as far I can tell) then invokes Javascript to get the new data.

I'm hoping there is some way around this so I can use scrapy and not selenium since selenium is slow. Some progress I have I made is that I found URLs of the following type (I don't remember how I found this out sadly):

https://www.nycenet.edu/offices/d_chanc_oper/budget/dbor/galaxy/galaxybudgetsummaryto/default.aspx?DDBSSS_INPUT=M015

can bring you directly to the data for the school (without having to interact with forms or Javascript I think). Unfortunately, I have only been able to get this method to work for the year 2019.

Would somebody be able to find a way to structure the URL so as to be able to specify the year? Or perhaps somebody can let me know if this isn't possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the network tab of your browser's dev tools you will notice that it is all about pretty standard post request. You can reproduce it with [Scrapy's FormRequest](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#formrequest-objects).

```py
yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
    response, 
    formid='form1', 
    formdata={'School_Code': 'm015', 'Fiscal_Year': '2019'},
    callback=self.parse_school  # for instance
)
```

Comment: Sorry I'm not very familiar with this stuff. How were you able to figure this out from the network tab of the browser's dev tools?

Comment: One other question! Would this possible to operationalize using the requests library you think?